# Python method from view.py not getting call on django template

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I am trying to call a  python view method res() on django template but its not getting call.

This is my View

```
class make_incrementor(object):
       def __init__(self, start):
          self.count=start
       def __call__(self, jump=1):
          self.count += jump
          return self.count

       @property
       def res(self):
          self.count =0
          return self.count
def EditSchemeDefinition(request, scheme_id):

    iterator_subtopic = make_incrementor(0)
    scheme_recs = scheme.objects.get(id=scheme_id)
    view_val = {
        'iterator_subtopic': iterator_subtopic,
        "scheme_recs": scheme_recs,
    }
    return render(request, "edit.html", view_val)
```

I am Trying to Increment the count and later resetting it to 0 after a level But its reset method is not getting call from the Django template.

This is my edit.html page

```
<td id="subTopic" class="subTopic">
    {% for strand in  scheme_recs.stand_ids.all %}
        {{ iterator_subtopic.res }}
        {% for sub_strand in  strand.sub_strand_ids.all %}
            {% for topic in  sub_strand.topic_ids.all %}
                {% for subtopic in  topic.sub_topic_ids.all %}
                    <input id="subTopic{{ iterator_subtopic }}" class="len"
                           value="{{ subtopic.name }}">
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</td>
```

my {{ iterator_subtopic.res }} is not getting the call and the value of iterator_subtopic is not get set to 0 again. The Function and its call is working fine on Terminal but not rendering in django template.

Please correct me where i am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply modify my make_incrementor class methods like:-

```
class make_incrementor(object):
count = 0

def __init__(self, start):
    self.count = start

def inc(self, jump=1):
    self.count += jump
    return self.count

def res(self):
    self.count = 0
    return self.count

def EditSchemeDefinition(request, scheme_id):

iterator_subtopic = make_incrementor(0)
scheme_recs = scheme.objects.get(id=scheme_id)
view_val = {
    'iterator_subtopic': iterator_subtopic,
    "scheme_recs": scheme_recs,
}
return render(request, "edit.html", view_val)
```

Later in my django template I called its method like:-

```
<td id="subTopic" class="subTopic">
<p hidden value="{{ iterator_subtopic.res }}"></p>
{% for strand in  scheme_recs.stand_ids.all %}
    {{ iterator_subtopic.res }}
    {% for sub_strand in  strand.sub_strand_ids.all %}
        {% for topic in  sub_strand.topic_ids.all %}
            {% for subtopic in  topic.sub_topic_ids.all %}
                <input id="subTopic{{ iterator_subtopic.inc  }}" class="len"
                       value="{{ subtopic.name }}">
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And its done. Now i am getting my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `make_incrementor` class has a `__call__` method, I believe that `{{ iterator_subtopic.res }}` will first call `iterator_subtopic()`, which will return the `count` integer. It will then try to access the `res` attribute of the `count` integer (which doesn't exist), so it will output the empty string `''`.